# Confused on usage of JQuery Selector reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, so as i am working on a development project, i started doing my normal object reference acquisition `var obj = $(".selector");` but then noticed that when i tried to operate on this reference it was not the root object.

[image]

Currently have JQuery 2.1 & JQuery UI 1.10.4 in the link folder.

Any explanation as to why i have use the Index 0 to get a reference to the html control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery selector returns a jQuery `QuerySet` object, which includes the set of results matching the query. It also allows you to call jQuery functions on the result, such as `.text()`, `.addClass()`, etc., instead of using the JavaScript DOM API.

As for why elements are accessible through indexing (vs, say, a property called `domElement` or something): remember that jQuery selector queries can return multiple elements. Imagine, for example, if you had multiple elements with the class "selector". Then `wnd[0]` will return the first matching DOM element, and `wnd[1]` will return the second matching DOM element.

Comment: Good answer,  Just to add that using $("#chat") is confusing Bec you know it is only one element, so you think that this jquery object IS the same element,  BUT knowing that $("li") or $(".item") will return a list of elements, then it will be clear that the jQuery object $() will contain one or more elements,  and accessing them should be by indexing,  e.g. $("li")[3] means accessing the 4th DOM element inside the jQuery object

Comment: in using previous 1.9+, all i had to do was do `var obj = $(".selector");` to operate with the control.  With this new implementation, i have to go to the first index to get the reference to the actual object to operate on it, like placement, value, etc.

Comment: @stackunderflow yeah but to assume all objects have an array of objects without verifying the type is a little over redundant.  If i had a `$("li")` then you should only iterate over its `children` if you want to get any innerHtml.  Think someone overthought or oversimplified the process to fit every situation.

Comment: @EyasSH i assume the implementation doesn't regard a difference between `$(".selector")`, `$("#selector")`, or `$("selector")`.  So now i will have to always take the first index of the selector in order to get the object.  This blows, would have rather had a `child` or `children` accessor instead of always having to take the first object in an array, even if there is only one.  Poor implementation or validation of use, in my eyes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you are using jQuery, you do *not* typically want to index at all. When you index you are getting the inner native JavaScript DOM Element and operating on it. If you are using jQuery, then it is because you are interested in operating on `QuerySet` objects and using jQuery functions. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @GoldBishop in addition I don't think anything changed from 1.9 to 2.0 in how to use QuerySet elements you get from a selector.

Comment: There is misunderstanding that you couldn't ask about it clearly in your question

Comment: In any selector that represents a list of elements jQuery also supplies a couple of methods to get to individual elements, such as `:eq()` and/or `.eq()`, `:first-child`, `.first()`, etc. So I am unsure of what the OP is after here. @GoldBishop can you clarify?

Comment: yeah, i did some review of my older JQuery (< 1.10) and found that all the operations i employed were function operations.  I stand way corrected and made some assumptions of accessing the actual property instead of using functions.